# how to use blazor server and blazor webassembly together in one project

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I have a project that has two pages and I need to create page one with blazor web assembly and create page two with blazor server side any idea on how to configure the project for this point?

Comment: you cant run a mix of server & wasm together, it's due to happen for .net 7

Comment: can I see any reference to show me that happens in .net 7?

Comment: because one of the Microsoft engineers told me it is possible

Comment: https://youtu.be/3o91I6lD-Bo?t=3179 see that slide top right first item where it shows "Mix Blazor Server and WebAssembly" , however this is wish list of what we may or not get, I'm watching this space keenly, if you do find anything please postback..!

Comment: I found this https://itnext.io/blazor-switching-server-and-webassembly-at-runtime-d65c25fd4d8

Comment: The configuration on Server for **Blazor WASM** and **Blazor Server** its too different. in .NET 6.0 you can not mixed this two type of Blazor projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This future will be available in Blazor .net 8
for more information, visit [.net 8 preview 5 features](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-8-preview-5/)

Answer (score 3):

The two hosting models cannot be mixed in one *project* at the time (in NET 6.0), as far as I know. However, there may be certain workarounds that provide what you need for your use case. Granted, I have little insights into your use case and why you would need a page from different hosting models, so these may not work for you.

### Alternative 1:

You can use the third hosting model option, Blazor WASM Hosted, which is a Blazor WASM client served from an ASP.NET Core server project. With this, you can do everything you need on both client- and server-sides. This hosting model provides a lot of flexibility and advantages (e.g. prerendering). While it mainly uses HTTP to communicate between the two, you can use SignalR as well.

### Alternative 2:

Alternatively, you could make two separate projects (one WASM and one Server) that you point to the same domain (with either a subdirectory for each, or different subdomains). It's more work to host this, and you may need to different build pipelines - still, it may work for your needs if the two pages are separate and independent.

---

Edit: This is coming to .NET 8 and Blazor United.